# How to correctly set headers in restlet api (via camel) to prevent warning: "Addition of the standard header "Pragma" is discouraged..."

Tags: java, apache-camel, restlet

Setting http headers directly and not via with [restlet api](https://restlet.com/open-source/documentation/user-guide/2.3/core/http-headers-mapping) seems to be "discouraged". I am using restlet indirectly by using camel-restlet.

I need to set some headers:

```
public static void setNoCacheHeaders(Exchange exchange) {
    exchange.getIn().setHeader(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    exchange.getIn().setHeader(HttpHeaders.PRAGMA, "no-cache");
    exchange.getIn().setHeader(HttpHeaders.EXPIRES, "0");

}
```

The problem is that i get a warning logged on every request:
`[WARN ] 2017-11-11 23:50:36.230 [Restlet-14633842] LogFilter - Addition of the standard header "Pragma" is discouraged as a future version of the Restlet API will directly support it.`

But how to set the "Pragma" header correctly to prevent this warning?

I am using camel 2.20.0. i lately updated because of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10665

This fixed many of those warnings.

Comment: You can only turn off that WARN logging from Restlet by setting its level to ERROR.

Comment: so there is no way to set this header via restlet api?

Comment: Find out, and provide a github PR with a fix/improvement to Apache Camel and log a JIRA ticket!